# Regex Is Always Greedy

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever">test</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_1234">test</div>
</td>
<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever2">test</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_5678">test</div>
</td>
<td class="testing2">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever2">test2</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_9012">test</div>
</td>
```

And I have the following regex that tries to get both 1234 and 5678:

```
~class="testing">\s*?<strong>.*?<a href=".*?">test</a>.*?<div class="body" id="id_(.*)">~Us
```

However, this returns only 5678, and not both:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5678
    )
```

How could I make it use the shortest overall match? I already use the ? modifier after every .*, as well as the U modifier at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you using regex to parse html document, there is much better ways to do this

Comment: I only need to extract these numbers, so it seemed like overkill to use an entire library when I can do it with just a simple preg_match().

Comment: You fool! You court the [wrath of the Elder Gods](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Also, you know PCRE **is** an *entire library*, right?

Comment: Your regexp specifically matches `class="testing"`. The second one has `class="testing2"`, so it doesn't match.

Comment: Er, my mistake. I created the example as a watered-down version of what I was trying to do, the problem still persists when you change "testing2" to "testing", I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DOM and XPath

```
$html = <<<_HTML
<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever">test</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_1234">test</div>
</td>
<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever2">test</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_5678">test</div>
</td>
<td class="testing2">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever2">test2</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_9012">test</div>
</td>
_HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($doc);
$divs = $xp->query('//td[@class="testing" and //a[normalize-space(text())="test"]]/div[@class="body" and starts-with(@id, "id_")]');

$ids = array();
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $ids[] = substr($div->getAttribute('id'), 3);
}
```

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/GbKIj2

Comment: Solid, thanks. I wasn't aware of DOMDocument before, I'll read up on it.

Comment: @PaulB I've added what I think is a better example of what you're after from reading your [comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646380/regex-is-always-greedy/17646506?noredirect=1#comment25696948_17646405)

Comment: Haha, I was literally refreshing the page to ask if it was possible to match "test" even though it's not a node attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, picked it up pretty quickly and got it working for my main problem, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your pattern doesn't work is the misunderstanding of the U modifier.

The U doesn't make all the quantifier ungreedy (or lazy). The U modifier is a switch, and when you use it:

1) all the greedy quantifiers become ungreedy (or lazy)

2) all the ungreedy (or lazy) quantifiers become greedy.

Since you use the U modifier in your pattern, the `.*?` is greedy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all("/id\=\"id_([0-9]+)\"/g", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: I think he's already using `preg_match_all`, since he's getting a 2-dimensional array returned.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using preg_match_all(), not preg_match(). I need to be able to get the ID numbers for certain anchor text - in this case "test", which is why I include it in the regex.

Comment: @PaulB your better off parsing it with a dom parser

Answer (score 0):

This produces the results you are after:

```
<?php

$str = '<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever">test</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_1234">test</div>
</td>
<td class="testing">
    <strong><span><a href="whatever2">test2</a></span></strong>
    <div class="body" id="id_5678">test</div>
</td>';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/id\="id_([0-9]+)\"/m', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```